# Which Google Analytics settings should be copied when implementing Google Optimize with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

I'm setting Google Optimize on a website that has Google Tag Manager.

The official implementation article [Optimize and Google Tag Manager](https://support.google.com/360suite/optimize/answer/7359264?hl=en):

> Copy your existing Analytics tracking code, including any customizations that you’ve made. If your Analytics tags in Tag Manager have custom Analytics tracker settings you must include them in the Analytics create command.

Does it mean to also copy settings like the content groups, ecommerce, etc...?
(If so, maybe there's no reason to keep the analytics tracking code in tag manager, seems a bit redundant)

---

*I suggest adding `google-optimize` tag to this question, I don't have enough reputation to create new tags.*

Comment: Hey so dont worry. There are various ways to do that. 1. If there only GTM and no analytics initiation on the page (If analytics tracking code is in tag manager), just copy and paste the Optimize installation code before the GTM installation code. It will work fine. 2. If you have the Ga initialization code in your web pages with GTM, please follow the steps provided in the doc you posted in your Question. And you dont have to copy settings like the content groups, ecommerce ;)

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps you could help me with the follow up question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295591/running-google-optimize-when-deploying-analytics-with-tag-manager-results-in-an